# How can I show an AlertDialog waking up the phone even when the device is locked and in sleep

Tags: java, android

I'm currently working on a project where I need to show notification of some new message and allow user to respond to it. I need the notification to come as an alertDialog, where I can provide some text with a timer. The user is allowed to respond within a fixed amount of time. If the user doesn't respond the dialog will go away.I need to show the alert dialog even when the device is locked and in sleep. When the notification comes up, the device has to wake up.

Any help will truly be appreciated. Thanks a million

Comment: Why can't you just use a notification? You can add a custom layout and style it however you like.

Comment: You can use Firebase Cloud Messaging (push notifications).

Comment: I need the dialog to stay on the screen. Show the timer with countdown. Allow users to respond. Can I display a timer in push notification?